# Send Form back and from two views in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I am making a project that involves users being able to write inside a Form and then save it as a markdown file. I need to find a way to show the user how does the markdown he is currently writing would look already once parsed; this would be shown on a separate static page with a return button to go back to writing.

This last part is giving me problems since I manage to show the user how his file would look like yet I haven't been able to find a way to render it back to the original entry form where it came from

### Preview HTML

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Preview</h1>

    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <hr>
    
    {{preview|safe}}

    <form action="{% url 'new_entry' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" name="return" value="Return">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

### New Entry HTML

```
{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>New Entry</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="{% url 'new_entry' %} " method="POST">
            {{form.as_table}}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Preview" name="preview">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

### Views for Preview and New HTML

```
def preview(request):
    #Retrieve data from the request
    form = EntryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        body = form.cleaned_data['body']

    # Nonfunctioning part
    #It's supposed to return the request to the original function
    #and letting it know that it has to pre-populate the form
    if 'return' in request.POST:
        return new_entry(request, fill_form=True)

    #Render the contents of the form
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry_preview.html",
    {"title":title,"preview":body})


def new_entry(request, fill_form = False): 

    #Non functioning part
    #Supposedly should get the request that the view 'preview'
    #recieved and get the form from there
    form = EntryForm()
    if fill_form is True:
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        body = form.cleaned_data['body']

    #If form returned submit then save the file
    if 'submit' in request.POST:
        util.save_entry(title,body)     
        return redirect(reverse('new_entry'))
    #If form returned preview then call function to display
    #users input rendered correctly     
    elif 'preview' in request.POST:
        #Pass the POST request to this other function
        return preview(request)
    #Else just render an empty form
    else:   
        return render(request,'encyclopedia/new_entry.html',
        {'form':form})
```

The Form is based on a Model, it just contains two basic fields, `title` and `body`.

Either way is open to other ideas to deal with this, my problem is mostly that when the function `preview` is called, it renders the passed values but now the passed parameters are gone, and am unable to return to the `new_entry` view.
Also, I thought of passing data through the URL but the body could be thousands of words long.

Comment: When the user clicks the "Back" button of the browser, they don't do a call to your view function because browser loads the page from the history. So, your users will have to reload the page. The other thing, IMHO, if you do it in a way that you split the window into two parts and on one side you have the form, on the other you have the preview part and you display the preview while the user is writing. Just like in stack overflow. Let me know if you choose to do it this way, I'll comment my advises.

Comment: That actually sounds even more interesting than what I planned on doing originally actually, I went with the "easier" route of just loading the parsed Markdown on a new static page for simplicity's sake. I am indeed interested on going with "live" version of the preview but I have no idea how would I tackle it, I have only used Django for completely static pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up with the comments, I will briefly explain one way of tackling this problem. For this task I would use a very tiny django library called [django_htmx](https://pypi.org/project/django-htmx/). Just take a look at the usage of [htmx](https://htmx.org) and in less than ten minutes you will be ready to implement it with ease. Your form will look something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'new_entry' %}" 
      data-hx-post="{% url 'new_entry' %}" 
      data-hx-target="#your-container-id"
      data-hx-swap="innerHTML"
      method="POST">
      {{form.as_table}}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Preview" name="
</form>
```

`data-hx-post` specifies the url to post this form via ajax. And `data-hx-target` specifies the container where the response from the ajax request will be inserted into. `data-hx-swap` tells htmx to insert the response into that container.

Put your `encyclopedia/entry_preview.html` template in an include block. And include it in the same page as the form. Don't forget to give the container element an ID so that you can target it in htmx with `data-hx-target`.
In your view function, you can say:

```
def new_entry(request, fill_form = False): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.htmx:
            # The request is made with htmx ajax call...
            # So we render only one side of the page. The display side.
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry_preview.html",
                         {"title":title,"preview":body})
       else:
          #render the page normally here. both with form and with preview container.
```

Give it a go and ask if you are stuck. You will have a nice dynamic markdown editing page.

PS: You can use `data-hx-trigger` to make it so that it updates even while typing. exactly like Stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Awesome! This solved my problem perfectly well and also it was really easy and intuitive, the documentation was neat and clear. I was just left with one small detail, the way I got it to update the preview is by having a `hx-trigger = every 100ms` since if I had `hx-trigger=change` it would update but only when I deselected the textarea. My solution perhaps is not as effective because is making a POST request every 100ms. Perhaps could you help me there. Either way thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you can use this one: `hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:1s"` so that it posts "on keyup, but only if the search value has changed and the user hasn't typed anything new for 1 second"